# How I get impression level log data using facebook api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I am working on facebook api. I can get total impression and clicks etc. data from facebook campaigns stats report. But my requirement is to get each impression in individual line. For example if campaign stats report shows 100 impression than I want to know 100 impression individually where they shown. Can anybody help me how I achieve this functionality of facebook marketing api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hej,

You can breakdown the data by platform, device and such (check Facebook API Documentation about [Breakdowns](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns#combiningbreakdowns) ) but as far as I am aware the API always aggregates Views that come from the same source or occurred in the same timeframe.

Comment: Thanks Nils Ole. These aggregation we can use on reporting. But my requirement is to get information of each impression like where this impression shown (lat, long), device user id, which os android or ios etc.

Comment: There are breakdowns for Device but no real info about the OS, apart from IOS or Android, but only for mobile devices. As far as I am aware there is no data on the desktop OS.

I am not sure what you mean by lat, long as there are only certain ad formats you can book on FB that have a specific position on the website/ in the app.

But frankly, I believe your case is too specific for the data that FB provides via API.